# Json Path extractor using Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, json

Using Json extractor from the below response I would like to extract the only `customerProductIdentifier` where `highLevelProduct` is `HSI`, and in my next Json extractor similarly would like to extract the `customerProductIdentifier` where `highLevelProduct` is `VOICE` or `CTL_PRISM`

```json
{
    "recordsChoice": [
        {
            "listedName": "EMA WATSON",
            "address": {
                "streetAddress": "",
                "addressLine1": "1900 SKY FLOWER CT",
                "addressLine2": "LAS VEGAS, NV"
            },
            "recordIdentifier": "310290154",
            "accountStatus": "Open"
        }
    ],
    "rxSessionIdentifier": "33062565",
    "accountInformation": {
        "billingIdentifier": "310290154",
        "billingName": "HANDY SHOWROOM",
        "billingAddress": {
            "streetAddress": "",
            "addressLine1": "1900 SKY FLOWER CT",
            "addressLine2": "LAS VEGAS, NV"
        },
        "customerType": "Consumer",
        "customerSubType": "Regular",
        "allServicesDeniedForNonPayment": false,
        "accountStatus": "Open",
        "isMilitaryAccount": false,
        "primaryClassOfServiceCode": "N.A",
        "classOfService": "N.A",
        "usocsOnAccount": [
            "IL",
            "WA"
        ],
        "hasPrism": true,
        "isMadisonRiverCustomer": false,
        "customerDateTime": "01/02/2019 03:58",
        "customerTimeGMTOffset": "-08:00",
        "customerTimeZoneAbbreviation": "US/Pacific",
        "legacyDispatchTerritory": "QCENTER",
        "billingSystem": "QCENTER",
        "smsDigitalDialogPreferences": {
            "repairSubscription": false,
            "defaultContact": false,
            "invalidFlag": false,
            "billingSubscription": false,
            "orderSubscription": false
        },
        "emailDigitalDialogPreferences": {
            "subscribedEmail": "hotel_reserv@hathway.com",
            "repairSubscription": true,
            "defaultContact": true,
            "marketingSubscription": true,
            "billingSubscription": true,
            "orderSubscription": true
        }
    },
    "serviceLines": [
        {
            "centralOffice": "LVSSNV",
            "locationTimeZone": "US/Pacific",
            "serviceAddress": {
                "streetAddress": "",
                "addressLine1": "1210 STRATOSPHERE",
                "city": "LAS VEGAS",
                "stateProvince": "NV",
                "postalCode": "89123-3959",
                "countryCode": "USA"
            },
            "hasGPON": false,
            "accessTech": "ADSL2PB",
            "hasVectoring": false,
            "isNIC": false,
            "isClickConverted": true,
            "isPrivateCarriage": false,
            "isVISP": false,
            "hasProfile17a": false,
            "hasInsideWireMaintenancePlan": true,
            "serviceTnOrCktId": "8861061786",
            "customerProducts": [
                {
                    "customerProductIdentifier": "314417931",
                    "ossProfile": {
                        "ossProfileName": "TraditionalEnsembleClick",
                        "billingSource": "Ansemble",
                        "inventorySource": "MARTENS",
                        "ticketingSystem": "OneRemedy",
                        "dispatchSystem": "Click"
                    },
                   "usoc": "WA",
                    "otherUsocs": [],
                    "highLevelProduct": "HSI",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "activationDate": "12/12/1985 00:00",
                    "productStatus": "Active",
                    "hasAtEaseFeature": false,
                    "purchasedSpeedDownKbps": "10000",
                    "purchasedSpeedUpKbps": "768",
                    "connectionType": "IPOE",
                    "isCentralizedBRAS": "false",
                    "sourceOfOpenSessionInfo": "BRAS"
                },
                {
                    "customerProductIdentifier": "314417930",
                    "ossProfile": {
                        "ossProfileName": "TraditionalEnsembleClick",
                        "billingSource": "Ensemble",
                        "inventorySource": "FCAS",
                        "ticketingSystem": "JACKS",
                        "dispatchSystem": "Click"
                    },
                    "usoc": "IL",
                    "otherUsocs": [],
                    "highLevelProduct": "VOICE",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "activationDate": "09/21/2014 00:00",
                    "productStatus": "Active",
                    "hasAtEaseFeature": false
                },
                {
                    "customerProductIdentifier": "314417929",
                    "ossProfile": {
                        "ossProfileName": "TraditionalEnsembleClick",
                        "billingSource": "Ansemble",
                        "inventorySource": "FCAS",
                        "ticketingSystem": "JACKS",
                        "dispatchSystem": "Click"
                    },
                    "usoc": "IL",
                    "otherUsocs": [],
                    "highLevelProduct": "CTL_PRISM",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "activationDate": "09/21/2014 00:00",
                    "productStatus": "Active",
                    "hasAtEaseFeature": false,
                    "connectionType": "IPOE",
                    "isCentralizedBRAS": "false",
                    "sourceOfOpenSessionInfo": "BRAS"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "apiResponse": {
        "code": 0,
        "type": "S",
        "message": "Success"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For extracting `customerProductIdentifier` where `highLevelProduct` is `HSI`:

   ```
   $..[?(@.highLevelProduct  == 'HSI')].customerProductIdentifier
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]
2. For extracting `customerProductIdentifier` where `highLevelProduct` is `VOICE` or `CTL_PRISM`:

   ```
   $..[?(@.highLevelProduct  == 'VOICE ' || @.highLevelProduct  == 'CTL_PRISM')].customerProductIdentifier
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

References:

- [JSON Path: Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri it helped a lot , can you please let me know similar path using JsonPath for restAssured